# Each loop with if condition in Jade-Template

Tags: html, node.js, express, pug, each

Hej.

I'm trying to write an `tr` just at the beginning and after every 9th element.
To do so I use the modulo Operator as you can see in the example above.
**But** if I would like to write `td`'s in between into that same `tr` with an `else` condition for example it creates another `tr`.

Does anybody see what's wrong? Or how it could work?

**Code Example**

```
extends layout.jade

    block body  
       table  
         each result, i in results
         if (i%9==0)
           tr
             td.ranking
             div.rank
                p=(i+1)+'.'
                div.points
                   p=result.points
                div.person                              
                   p.name=result.name
                   p=result.company  
         else
             td.ranking
             div.rank
                p=(i+1)+'.'
                div.points
                   p=result.points
                div.person                              
                   p.name=result.name
                   p=result.company
```

**HTML output**

[image: Jade Html output]

Comment: Is my understanding correct: you would like to have content of `results` displayed as `td`'s of 9 per a `tr`?

Comment: Yes @Tom that's right.

Comment: I have posted one of the possible solutions. I always perform split into 2D array when I have similar problem to solve. Jade template is not very helpful with that operations (at least for me ;) ) so I prefer to handle parameter transformations inside handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solutions would be as follows:

Let's say you have a variable `results` in your express handler:

```
var results =  ['a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r'];
```

Note that this might be an array of objects. For simplicity purposes I used strings from `a` through `r.

Let's split that array into 2 dimensional array of rows and columns:

```
var results2d = [];
while(results[0]) {
     results2d.push(results.splice(0, 9));
}
```

I always prefer to perform all transformations inside express handlers in order to reduce number of additional lines of codes inside a template.

So your `results2d` would be as follows:

```
[ [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h' ],
  [ 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p' ],
  [ 'q', 'r' ] ]
```

Then you can pass it over to the Jade template:

```
res.render('templateId', { results:results2d  });
```

Inside the template your code could be as follows:

```
table  
    - var i = 1;
    each result in results
        tr
            each item in result
                td.ranking
                    div.rank
                        p=(i++)+'.'
                        div.points
                            p=result.points
                        div.person                              
                            p.name=result.name
                            p=result.company
```

And your HTML output would be as follows:

[image: results]

I hope that will help.